# Getting url parameters in node with express

Tags: node.js, express

I feed a bit stupid asking this but I can't get it to work somehow.
I want to call the page using something like this.
http://localhost:3000/testParam?id=4&token=sdfa3
I did some research and articles say you can do it like this:
(also some say req.param.var_name but seems to be deprecated)

```
app.get("/testParam", function (req, res) {
    let id = req.query.id;
    let token = req.query.token;
    res.send(`Those are your params ${id} and ${token}`);
});
```

It gives back "undefined".
I want the id and token separately. I am using node 8.4 (same with 9.4).

Comment: Body parser isn't relevant.  `req.query` should be populated anyway.  Are you *sure* those parameters are making it to your Node.js application?  I suspect they aren't.  Use a packet sniffer to verify.

Comment: i am pretty sure that they make it to my application. if i print ${req.query()} i get id=4&token=sdfa3 so that works but i need them split up,

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. I'm using v9.3.0. Try printing id and token on the console from your server.

Comment: Your example works for me using ```express@4.16.2```. May I ask you to try it using that exact same version? I tested this using a minimalist setup. Simply put ```var app = require('express')();``` before and ```app.listen(8000);``` after your code block.

Comment: Oh, i just found out what it was. I used restify before and i still had `var restify = require("restify");` on top so that messed things up